# How to enable PRACK(100rel) with Zoiper client

Tags: sip

I am using Zoiper softphone for my call tests. I would like to add "Require: 100rel" to the INVITE message in order to send a PRACK after 180 ringing response. I have found the config.xml under %APPDATA%\Zoiper but not sure how to modify it to support 100rel in INVITE for PRACK.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PRACK is to make provisional responses reliable.
If Zoiper doesn't have this in it's settings, I don't think that it will be "reliable" if you hack it from it's config.xml :)

(probably this feature was not tested enough to be added on Zoiper setting GUI page)